# Serial Incremental bash loop running 2 processes in parallel

Tags: bash

```
#!/bin/bash -l 
ind() {
if [[ $1 -lt 10 ]] ; then
 return 00$1
elif [[ $1 -lt 100 ]] ; then
 return 0$1
elif [[ $1 -lt 1000 ]] ; then
 return $1
fi
}

for i in `seq 0 2 127`
do    
  j=$(($i+1))
  ii=$(ind $i)
  jj=$(ind $j)
  echo "ii jj here"  "${ii}" "${jj}" 
runA $ii & runA $jj &
done
```

I would expect this to give me output like

000 001

002 003

004 005

...

010 011

...

126 127

so that in this loop I will run 2 jobs in parallel with $ii and $jj being their respective inputs, just shown symbolically, no output is produced by them here.

It gives me nothing:

ii jj here
ii jj here

I must be doing something very silly, fundamentally wrong, although I am quite experienced. Can you please help me? This is not a homework.

Many thanks for reading.
....

Comment: `return` != `echo` . `return 00$1` padding with zeros? Just `printf "%04d" "$1"`

Comment: You are running several `runA` processes in parallel (not just two of them, since the next operation of the loop most likely spawns again two `runA` before the ones from the previous iteration are finished). Furthermore, you don't tell us what happens inside `runA`, so I can't comment on the output which you can expect.

Comment: BTW, since you are using bash, the loop can be written simpler as `for i in  {0..127..2}`.

Comment: Many great many thanks to all of you.

Answer (score 0):

Ah, I was returning a return status of the process, not a result.
[https://linuxize.com/post/bash-functions/#:~:text=To%20invoke%20a%20bash%20function,any%20calls%20to%20the%20function](https://linuxize.com/post/bash-functions/#:%7E:text=To%20invoke%20a%20bash%20function,any%20calls%20to%20the%20function).

corrected code is:

```
#!/bin/bash -l 
ind() {
if [[ $1 -lt 10 ]] ; then
 res="00$1"
elif [[ $1 -lt 100 ]] ; then
 res="0$1"
elif [[ $1 -lt 1000 ]] ; then
 res="$1"
fi
}

for i in `seq 0 2 127`
do    

  ind $i
  ii=$res
   
  j=$(($i+1))
  ind $j

  jj=$res
  echo "ii jj here"  "${ii}" "${jj}" 
done
```